# Which ships are suited to farming the "tags for sec" NPCs in low-sec?

Tags: eve-online

In the Odyssey expansion CPP added a new way to regain security status, the [Tags for Security Status feature](http://community.eveonline.com/news/dev-blogs/wanttotrade-tags-for-security-status/). There are new NPCs in low-sec belts that drop tags which can be traded for a security status gain.

I thought I might try to farm those a bit and repair my security status a bit. Which ships would be best suited for this purpose? They should be reasonably cheap for the case that I'm caught, so no pirate faction or T3 ships. They should be able to kill the NPCs effectively, but still small or cloaky enough to get through the inevitable gate camp.

Comment: Would be helpful to add what you can fly, as in race and shipclasses.

Comment: I can fly most stuff up to BC size fom all four races, so I intentionally didn't restrict it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats my lowsec Ratting Manticore. The trick is that the 2 Painters will help the manticore to apply its decent damage on the cruiser sized Clone Warrior NPC. Even with my average skills (Torps only sitting at 3, Missile base skills at 4) I'm able to plop the NPC before Im even taking any damage at all. Thats why the MSB may be debatable but I keep it as a failsafe guard for now. Gives you the time to warp off in case something goes wrong. I think about swapping it for either a small or none at all (your signature size is your #1 defense)

I tried all sorts of tanking the NPC before and always ended up in armor and with burned modules. With the setup below it's a nobrainer. Just don't forget to enable the TPs ;-)) Attack range will be about 30km - you may want to even get a closer in order to make for shorter Torp flight time. It's all about plopping him before he even really starts shooting at you. You could tank a couple of rounds though.

```
[Manticore]
1x Covert Ops Cloaking Device II
1x Core Probe Launcher I
3x Prototype 'Arbalest' Torpedo Launcher

Medium power
1x 1MN Afterburner II
2x Target Painter II
1x Medium Shield Extender II

Low power
1x Ballistic Control System II
1x Micro Auxiliary Power Core I

Rig Slot
1x Small Bay Loading Accelerator I
1x Small Warhead Calefaction Catalyst I
```

Answer (score 2):

Covert Ops Class Ships are not capable of fighting those Rats, since they are either too weak (Scanning Covert Ops) or have the wrong weapon size (Stealth Bomber).

Since you ruled out T3, the only ships left that can cloak and warp are Force Recon Class Ships or Black Ops. However, I think they are too expensive to actually do the job of ratting efficiently.

I think the best ship to do that would be an Assault Frigate and there either the Ishkur or the Jaguar or Wolf. All those 3 are excellent Ratters in lowsec (I actually did some ratting with the Ishkur in nullsec too and it worked great., I also have PvP experience in that ship) and rather cheap. One complete setup comes around 35 mil, depending on daily prices, if you go for complete T2 fitting. They are  also well suited for a lowsec pvp fight, which will happen. All 3 Ships can easily take on a player piloted Frigate or Cruiser, except the Cynabal (also known as Frigate Killer).

They also have the advantage of being very agile, rendering gate camps nearly useless against them, unless they use remote sensor boosters and have instant lock-ons but in that case a cloaked ship would most likely get caught either. (You are visible in the overview between gate cloak and module cloak for a second) I'd just fit 2 warp core stabs when jumping from high to low, dock and exchange them for my ratting modules.

It is also important to have Spaceship Command on Level 5, since it adds more agility, as well as Armor Honeycombing in case of the Ishkur.

If you don't want to use any T2 Ship, then I'd just go for a cheap cruiser like the Thorax or Vexor to rat. I stick to Gallente in Lowsec since 99% of the fights are done brawling and there Gallente really shines with their Blasters.

As Eve Online is a Sandbox, there might be of course other methods of handling it, but I feel the Assault Ship approach is the best one.

Aside from all that, I'd just look for a calm lowsec that does not have any gate camps during your usual play time.

General Tips for ratting in lowsec:

- Go to Minmatar or Gallente Space if you can.
- Stay away from lowsec around Lower Debyl and Jita (those are used by nullsec alliances to bring stuff in)
- Don't rat in the transit system between high and low. Go deeper into lowsec. It is safer there.
- Stay away from lowsecs near trading hubs or mission runner systems, those attract all kind of shady folks.
- Look at your map and show data for pod kills and npc kills in the last hour. That gives you a nice overview how active that sector is.
- Make friends with residents in lowsec. Many have intel channels and form up to remove any disturbances in their space.
- Have multiple safespots, far away from any celestial. Warp around if you are hunted.
- Never sit on a safespot, always move into a direction with AB or MWD on. That makes it harder to scan you down.
- Don't chat in local unless you see a chance to make a friend, don't smacktalk
- Say "good fight" in local, even if you got shot down. Don't write any angry mails or comments to pirates, also called "fan mail".
- Never accept fleet invites, make sure you don't have a public fleet open.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.angrygamersinc.com/reports/eve-online/living-in-lowsec-pt-1-paying-the-bills-with-clone-soldiers/

AFs are just fine since except for Guristas you are speed tanking mostly. I prefer interceptors due to their warp speed and agility (to me time between rats is more important than the time dealing with the rat itself...but your choice).

Source: Myself, I do these nearly daily. have hands-on experience with every single type of Clone Soldier except Blood Raider. I have a corpmate who verified my comments on Blood Raider rats in the article.

In my experience, Serpentis, Sansha, and Angel are the easiest to kill (in that order with my interceptor setup). By this I assume Blood Raiders are easy as well since they are similar to Sansha. Guristas are most difficult, requiring an AF or T1 cruiser to properly tank the incoming inferno (yes, they are thermal and not kinetic) missiles.